# Como utilizar a função filter utilizando listas?

Tags: python, funções, filter

Estou tentando filtrar os meses com apenas 31 dias, no entanto mdays é uma lista e eu preciso comparar com um valor inteiro. Pegando pelo indice, torna-se um valor inteiro, mas aí não sei como utilizar visto q só poderei comparar um mes com a quantidade de dias (31). No exercicio, especificamente, o professor solicita o uso das funções map, filter e reduce.

```py
from calendar import mdays, month_name
   from functools import reduce


#Listar todos os meses do ano com 31 dias

apenas_31 = list(filter(lambda i: i[mdays[i]] > 30, mdays))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar `filter` e `lambda` vai ser mais complicado do que necessário aqui.

Recomendo utilizar uma **compreensão de lista**, que é mais legível, juntamente da função `enumerate`, que itera sobre os elementos de uma sequência juntamente de seus índices:

```
from calendar import mdays, month_name

apenas_31 = [month_name[i] for i, n in enumerate(mdays) if n > 30]
print(apenas_31)
```

output:

```
['January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'August', 'October', 'December']
```

Comment: Obrigada! O exercicio especificamente pedia para usar a função filter, mas realmente list comprehension é muito melhor!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme resposta do jfaccioni, o uso de **compreensão de lista** é o mais recomendado, pois é mais legível. Porém, para fins didáticos, irei demonstrar como seria uma possível solução usando apenas `map` e `filter`.

Dado que a função `filter(function, iterable)` retorna apenas os elementos de `iterable` onde a `function` retorna verdadeiro, podemos usá-la para filtrar o índice dos meses que tem 31 dias:

```
indice_meses_31d = filter(lambda i: mdays[i]==31, range(1,13))
```

e `map(function, iterable, ...)` aplica a função `function` a cada elemento de `iterable`, portanto:

```
nome_meses_31d = map(lambda i: month_name[i], indice_meses_31d)
```

Unindo as duas funções em uma única linha:

```
nome_meses_31d = map(lambda i: month_name[i], filter(lambda i: mdays[i]=31, range(1,13)))
```

Use `print(list(nome_meses_31d))` para exibir o nome dos meses com 31 dias.

### Código Completo:

```
from calendar import mdays, month_name
indice_meses_31d = filter(lambda i: mdays[i]==31, range(1,13))
nome_meses_31d = map(lambda i: month_name[i], indice_meses_31d)
print(list(nome_meses_31d))
```

ou

```
from calendar import mdays, month_name
nome_meses_31d = map(lambda i: month_name[i], filter(lambda i: mdays[i]==31, range(1,13)))
print(list(nome_meses_31d))
```